# Bootstrap columns has separate scrollbars

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have page structured in three parts: left-sidebar, content and right sidebar

```
<div class="row">

            <div class="col-lg-1 sidebar-left">
                ...(html content)
            </div><!-- /.sidebar-left -->

            <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-10 col-lg-offset-1">
                ...(html content)
            </div><!-- /.col-md-9 -->

            <div class="col-md-2 sidebar sidebar-right">
                ...(html content)
            </div> <!-- /.sidebar-right --> 

</div><!-- /.row -->
```

The problem ocurs when two elements are longer than screen height, and creates separate scrollbars for each elements. Any advice how to make the page with single scroll bar no matter the lenght of the elements?

screenshot of the problem:
[image: screenshot of the problem:]

Comment: I only see html tags in your code, no jsf (besides the include). This is with 99.9% certainty a non-jsf issue. Learn how to use a browser developer tool and see what CSS can be used to correct this

Comment: CSS is applied on HTML not on JSF. JSF is in the context of this question merely a HTML code generator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pure CSS problem. Both, left and right sidebar maybe have a `height` defined. So, when the children size exceed the defined height, the parent act. If has `overflow: hidden`, the exceed part is hidden, if has `overflow: scroll` or `overflow: auto` a scroll is added to view all elements.

You need to remove the fixed heights from both sidebars.